# jQuery Select2 is not displaying

Tags: jquery-select2

I am trying to use [select2](https://select2.org/). I added CSS & JS of select2 using below code.

```
<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/select2/4.0.11/css/select2.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/select2/4.0.11/js/select2.min.js"></script>
```

I am using below JS Code in my HTML page.

```
<script>
    $(document).ready(function() {
        $('.js-example-basic-multiple').select2({
            placeholder: 'Select an option'
        });
    });
</script>
```

My HTML is like below

```
<select class="js-example-basic-multiple" multiple="multiple">
    <option value="example1">example1</option>
    <option value="example2">example2</option>
    <option value="example3">example3</option>
    <option value="example4">example4</option>
    <option value="example5">example5</option>
    <option value="example6">example6</option>
</select>
```

I am using below jQuery link

```
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.4.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

But I am getting output like below

[image]

Comment: Your jquery file should be loaded before select2.js file.

Answer (score 1):

I have fixed your code please check it.

```js
$('#example').select2({
    placeholder: 'Select an option'
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.10.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://rawgit.com/select2/select2/master/dist/js/select2.js"></script>

<link href="https://rawgit.com/select2/select2/master/dist/css/select2.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />



<select id="example" multiple="multiple" style="width: 300px">
   <option value="example1">example1</option>
    <option value="example2">example2</option>
    <option value="example3">example3</option>
    <option value="example4">example4</option>
    <option value="example5">example5</option>
    <option value="example6">example6</option>
</select>
```

Comment: Thanks @chandu komati. I am getting `TypeError: $(...).select2 is not a function` error. Thanks.